# How to append a message to std::exception?

Tags: c++

I would like to do the following:

```
std::string fileName = "file";
std::ifstream in(fileName.c_str());
in.exceptions(std::istream::failbit);

try
{
    loadDataFrom(in);
}
catch (std::ios_base::failure& exception)
{
    std::string location = std::string(" in file\n") + fileName;
    // append the "location" to the error message;
    throw;
}
```

How can I append the error message to an exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can throw a new exception, with the augmented message:

```
throw std::ios_base::failure(exception.what() + location,
                             exception.code());
```

**Edit:** The second parameter `exception.code()` is from C++11.

**2nd edit:** Note that, if your caught exception is from a sub-class of `std::ios_base::failure`, you will lose parts of it, using my suggestion.

Comment: Thank you! But what if the catch clause catches an exception that only inherits `std::ios_base::failure`? Can I somehow benefit from the polymorphic behavior of `throw;` while appending the message?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik You are right. But I do not see any way to do that. The `what()` function from `std::exception` does not provide a way to modify the text.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can only take `what()` convert it to string, append, and re-throw the exception.

```
catch (std::ios_base::failure& exception)
{
    std::string location = std::string(" in file\n") + fileName;
    std::string error(exception.what());
    throw std::ios_base::failure(error+location);
    // throw std::ios_base::failure(error+location, exception.code()); // in case of c++11
}
```

Remember that since c++11 failure got a 2nd argument. You rather want to pass it too.